# MySql search script writes an unkown error

Tags: php, mysql

This is my second post on stackoverflow, and i hope u will help me resolve this one too.
When i run this script it says "Undefined variable: search_name".i don't know what is problem.
Hope u are going to help.
Ty :D .

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Error" .mysqli_connect_error();
}
if(isset($_POST['go']))
{
$search_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['form_name']);
}

$select_name=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test_mysql WHERE name='$search_name' ");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_name))
{
$ime=$row['name'];
$prezime=$row['lastname'];
$id_number=$row['id'];
echo $id_number." .  ".$ime. "  ".$prezime."<br>";
}





?>
<form action="" methom="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="form_name"/>
<input type="submit" value="send" name="go"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Ask yourself the question, what happens to your query, if `$_POST['go']` is not set.

Comment: yes when u load the page the POST data is not available and hence getting the error !! Move the query and while loop inside if(isset()) block

Comment: Can u see what i wrote below, and could u try to find mistaka again? :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your query inside the `isset()` of your submit button, otherwise the code will be executed everytime the page loads causing the error.

```
if(isset($_POST['go']))
{   
    $search_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['form_name']);
    $select_name=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test_mysql WHERE name='$search_name' ");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_name))
    {
        $ime=$row['name'];
        $prezime=$row['lastname'];
        $id_number=$row['id'];
        echo $id_number." .  ".$ime. "  ".$prezime."<br>";
    }    
}
?>
<form action="" methom="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="form_name"/>
<input type="submit" value="send" name="go"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, just make sure the form is submitted before building the query, you already do that but not to all the parts of the code

```
if(isset($_POST['go']))
{
    $search_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['form_name']);
    $select_name=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test_mysql WHERE name='$search_name' ");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_name))
    {
        $ime=$row['name'];
        $prezime=$row['lastname'];
        $id_number=$row['id'];
        echo $id_number." .  ".$ime. "  ".$prezime."<br>";
    }
}
```

This should solve it.

Comment: When i click "send" only url of the page changes from: http://localhost/form_2/search.php to: http://localhost/form_2/search.php?form_name=rifet&go=send